# How to turn off figure display while running plot scripts

Tags: matlab, plot, figure

I've created several bar chart and scatter dot scripts to plot my data. The problem is Matlab displays each plot as the plot is created, making things very disruptive (I can't do anything else until the plotting is completed). I've tried several methods posted on Mathworks.com and also [here on Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129622/disable-plots-in-matlab) but none of them worked. Here is an example of my code for scatter dots:

```
fig = figure(456);
scatter(Data(:,1),Data(:,2),'filled');
hold on;         
h = plot(Data(:,1),b,'-');
legend(h,sprintf('r = %s, p = %s',num2str(r),num2str(p)));
title(sprintf(<plot title>));
xlabel(sprintf('%s',set1.textdata{1,z+2}));
ylabel(sprintf('%s',set2.textdata{1,f+2}));
hold off
set(findall(fig,'type','text'),'fontSize',16,'fontweight','bold')
saveas(figure(456),fullfile(output_path, sprintf(<filename>));
close(fig)
```

Could anyone help? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this should work:

```
fig = figure('Visible', 'off');
scatter(Data(:,1),Data(:,2),'filled');
hold on;         
h = plot(Data(:,1),b,'-');
legend(h,sprintf('r = %s, p = %s',num2str(r),num2str(p)));
title(sprintf(<plot title>));
xlabel(sprintf('%s',set1.textdata{1,z+2}));
ylabel(sprintf('%s',set2.textdata{1,f+2}));
hold off
set(findall(fig,'type','text'),'fontSize',16,'fontweight','bold')
saveas(fig,fullfile(output_path, sprintf(<filename>));
close(fig)
```

Comment: The OP mentioned that he/she already tried all of the answers on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129622/disable-plots-in-matlab - and the answer you provided is included.... now what you suggested **should** work, and so I'm actually puzzled as to why it isn't.

Comment: I assumed the OP tried:
`fig = figure(456);
set(gcf,'Visible','off');` Which would still make them pop-up.
Otherwise, it must work. Right?  :-)

Comment: Using `fig = figure(456, 'Visible','off');` I got this error: Too many input arguments. Using `fig = figure(456); set(gcf,'Visible','off');` didn't stop the figure from popping up.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still unclear how you can do both - set the figure number and additional figure properties in one line, since I don't think you can do figure('Number',492).  Number is a read only property.  
But, as long as you are closing the figure right after this code anyway, there is no real need to set it to a particular number.  Alas, I have no Matlab license on this machine to play with.

Comment: You were correct, Matlab does not allow setting the figure number then declaring figure properties. The figure number is indeed not necessary so your answer works just fine. It's great that you answered my question even without having access to Matlab.